SQL Date Comparison With Month and Year in Separate Columns
I have a table (let's call it MyData) that has some information and also stores a month and a year in separate columns but no day, so it looks like this:



SomeData1
SomeData2
Month
Year
SomeDataN...




...
...
1
2021
...


...
...
2
2021
...


...
...
3
2021
...


...
...
8
2022
...


...
...
12
2022
...


...
...
5
2023
...


...
...
7
2023
...



I need to get all data from March 2021 to today.
I am trying to convert the Month and Year column into a date while also adding 01 as the day portion of the date (the specific day does not matter since it is not even stored in the table). I then want to compare this converted date from the table to my required date of March 2021 ('2021-03-01). I'm not even sure if it is necessary to add the day portion to either of these as well.
I am really stuck and not sure how to do this. Maybe there is a simpler solution than converting into dates and comparing?
I've tried:
SELECT DATEFROMPARTS([Year], [Month], 01) AS DATE
               FROM dbo.MyData)

So now I have all the month/year columns in a date format but really not sure where to go from here.
I want to do something like
SELECT * FROM MyData
WHERE (SELECT DATEFROMPARTS([Year], [Month], 01) AS DATE
           FROM dbo.MyData)) > '2021-03-01'

Thanks in advance.

Sample data please. How are we to know if Month is MARCH or MAR or 03 or 3?

@Isolatedsorry was rushing and forgot to include it. I've edited so you can see the months are stored as m instead of mm

Please edit your question and add in the query that demonstrates your best attempt at resolving your problem and explain what results it's giving you versus what you expect.  This will help us better understand the problem.

Ideally, convert to dates as a new column in your table. However, if it's just a 1-time query and your data are indeed integers, then you simply need where month >= 3 and year >= 2021.

Just another option add another column with a computed/persisted value of DATEFROMPARTS([Year], [Month], 1)

@Isolated:  that would not return January in 2022....

@Luuk yep you are correct, tried that and it did not return Jan 2022. The correct answer was posted below.

@JohnCappelletti thanks, this is helpful. I can't alter the table but adding the original columns and this new column to a temp table and doing the comparison from the new column in the temp table will work

@Luuk Oops, didn't think that thru. :( Long day time to go home.

@Isolated " Long day time to go home." I feel you, kind of the whole purpose behind this post lol

I don't get it, why didn't: WHERE DATEFROMPARTS([Year], [Month], 01)  >= '20210301' work? All the other solutions hose the indexes anyway, but if you have a year index, you can always add: AND YEAR >= 2021

In your case the best solution is to combine two where condition like following.
SELECT [Data]
      ,[Month]
      ,[Year]
FROM [Test].[dbo].[Table]
WHERE ([Month] >= 3 AND [Year] = 2021) OR [Year] > 2021


Thank you this worked. I knew there was a more simple solution than what I was getting at

This should work:
SELECT *
FROM MyData
WHERE DATEFROMPARTS([Year], [Month], 1) >= '20210301'

Note the lack of dashes in the date literal, which for historical reasons is correct for SQL Server.
However, it won't use any indexes on the year or month columns. This is one reason (among several) this data should have been stored as a DateTime column in the first place.

Using outer apply gives it it's own column which helps in handling the issue: the date value can be used both in the output and in the filtering:
SELECT t
FROM dbo.MyData
Outer apply (select 
DATEFROMPARTS([Year], [Month], 01)[t])t
Where t > '2021-03-01'


If you want to compare the whole date, you can convert your data to date. This will work. Hard-coded first
select reverse(substring(reverse(cast(5 as varchar)) + '000', 1, 2)) + '/01/' + cast(1111 as  varchar) 

That gives you 05/01/1111
dynamic - substitute with real columns
Select 
    t.somedata1,
    realDate
from 
    (select
        somedata1, 
        (reverse(substring(reverse(cast([Month] as varchar)) + '000', 1, 2)) + '/01/' + cast([Year] as  varchar)) as realDate
     from MyData) t
where realdate between @1 and @2

